# How to fix "could not load from Adreno device driver:eglGetError"

Tags: android, sdk, opengl-es-2.0, gpu

I installed AdrenoSDK 3.6 from [adreno-sdk.zip](https://developer.qualcomm.com/download/adreno-sdk.zip) on windows 7 64bit.

But when i run the samples from bin folder its reporting "could not load from Adreno device driver:eglGetError".

I don't know what may be causing it and what to do to get rid of it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long struggle and some answers from [qualcomm developer site](https://developer.qualcomm.com/forum/qdn-forums/maximize-hardware/mobile-gaming-graphics-adreno/27651) got the solution.

Install the x86 version of this redist.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Comment: 0
down vote
 

This doesn't work for me. I try both "Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4" x86 and x64 and still got same issue and crash.
Any ideas ?

Comment: I am using visual studio 10 essential edition on windows 7 which version is yours.

Comment: Hi ! That down vote text is just a garbage Ctrl-C/Ctrl-V. I didn't vote it down. About the issue, I'm using GCC 4.8 with JNI. The good thing about GCC is it doesn't create dependencies with VS-20XX runtime libs. But I'll try VS-2010 on my next debug session. Thanks !